# Repeated data in my spinner and ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a problem receiving data from my database. As determined in my codes, my database (TBL_MAHRIE) contains three columns **(ID , COL_SAL , COL_NERKH)**. Running my project, I received repeated data in both of spinner and ListView.

1. Mahrie.java (MY SPINNER LOAD HERE)

   ```
    package ir.dadpardaz.mahrie_dadpardaz; 
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

   public class Mahrie extends Activity {

   private Spinner spinner_sal1, spinner_sal2;
   private Button btn_calc;
   EditText ed_shakhes_Nekah, ed_shakhes_Motalebe;
   TextView tv_res;
   float shakhes_Nekah, shakes_Motalebe, final_Res;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_mahrie);

       ed_shakhes_Motalebe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_shakhes_Motalebe);
       ed_shakhes_Nekah = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_shakes_Nekah);
       tv_res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_res);

       // DATABASE
       DataBaseHandler databaseAdapter = new DataBaseHandler(this);

       Shakhes shakhes1 = new Shakhes("1392", "250");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes1);

       Shakhes shakhes2 = new Shakhes("1391", "200");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes2);

       Shakhes shakhes3 = new Shakhes("1390", "150");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes3);

       Shakhes shakhes4 = new Shakhes("1389", "100");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes4);

       Shakhes shakhes5 = new Shakhes("1388", "50");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes5);

       Shakhes shakhes6 = new Shakhes("1387", "25");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes6);

       addItemsOnSpinner2();
       addListenerOnButton();
       addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
       }

   // add items into spinner dynamically
   public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

       spinner_sal2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_Sal2);
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

       DataBaseHandler databaseAdapter = new DataBaseHandler(this);
       List<Shakhes> data_shakhes = null;
       data_shakhes = databaseAdapter.getAllShakhes();

       Context context = getApplicationContext();

       for (int i = 0; i < data_shakhes.size(); i++) {

           list.add((data_shakhes.get(i).getSal()));

       }

       ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
       dataAdapter
               .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner_sal2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   }

   public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
       spinner_sal1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_Sal1);
       spinner_sal1
               .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
   }

   // get the selected dropdown list value
   public void addListenerOnButton() {

       spinner_sal1 = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner_Sal1);
       spinner_sal2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_Sal2);
       btn_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_calc);

       btn_calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {

               shakhes_Nekah = Float.parseFloat(ed_shakhes_Nekah.getText()
                       .toString());
               shakes_Motalebe = Float.parseFloat(ed_shakhes_Motalebe
                       .getText().toString());
               final_Res = shakes_Motalebe / shakhes_Nekah;

               tv_res.setText(final_Res + "");             

           }

       });
   }
   }
   ```

2.DataBase Handler.java

```
package ir.dadpardaz.mahrie_dadpardaz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class DataBaseHandler {

    SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
        ShakhesDatabaseOpenHelper shakhesDatabaseOpenHelper = new ShakhesDatabaseOpenHelper(
                context, "shakhsdb.db", null, 1);
        database = shakhesDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public class ShakhesDatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public ShakhesDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ "TBL_MAHRIE");
            String query = "create table IF NOT EXISTS TBL_MAHRIE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, COL_SAL TEXT, COL_NERKH TEXT)";
            db.execSQL(query);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ "TBL_MAHRIE");
        }

    }

    public long insertShakhes(Shakhes shakhes) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("COL_SAL", shakhes.getSal());
        values.put("COL_NERKH", shakhes.getNerkh());
        return database.insert("TBL_MAHRIE", null, values);
    }

    boolean isTableExists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
        if (tableName == null || db == null || !db.isOpen()) {
            return false;
        }
        Cursor cursor = db
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = ? AND name = ?",
                        new String[] { "table", tableName });
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return false;
        }
        int count = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        return count > 0;
    }


    public List<Shakhes> getAllShakhes() {
        List<Shakhes> shakhess = null;

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TBL_MAHRIE",null);
        //Cursor c = database.query("TBL_MAHRIE", new String[] { "ID", "COL_SAL",   "COL_NERKH" }, null, null, null, null, null);
        shakhess = new ArrayList<Shakhes>();
        Shakhes p = new Shakhes();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {          
            do {
                p.setId((int) c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("ID")));
                p.setSal(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_SAL")));
                p.setNerkh(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_NERKH")));

                shakhess.add(p);
            } while (c.moveToNext()); 
            return shakhess;

    } 
        return shakhess;
        }

    }
```

1. Mahrie_JadvalActivity (My ListView inflate here)

   ```
   package ir.dadpardaz.mahrie_dadpardaz;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class Mahrie_JadvalActivity extends Activity {

   ListView personListView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_mahrie__jadval);

       personListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.personListView);
       DataBaseHandler databaseAdapter = new DataBaseHandler(this);        


       Shakhes shakhes1 = new Shakhes("2392" , "250");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes1);

       Shakhes shakhes2 = new Shakhes("2391" , "200");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes2);

       Shakhes shakhes3 = new Shakhes("2390" , "150");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes3);

       Shakhes shakhes4 = new Shakhes("2389" , "100");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes4);

       Shakhes shakhes5 = new Shakhes("2388" , "50");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes5);

       Shakhes shakhes6 = new Shakhes("2387" , "25");
       databaseAdapter.insertShakhes(shakhes6);                



       List<Shakhes> shakhes = 
       databaseAdapter.getAllShakhes() ;
       ShakhesListViewAdapter shakhesListViewAdapter = new ShakhesListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.mahrie_list_view_item, shakhes);
       personListView.setAdapter(shakhesListViewAdapter);      
   }

   public class ShakhesListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Shakhes> {

       List<Shakhes> data;
       Context context;

       public ShakhesListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<Shakhes> data) {
           super(context, resourceId, data);
           this.data = data;
           this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(final int position, View item, ViewGroup parent) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mahrie_list_view_item, parent , false);

           TextView familyTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.familyTextView);
           familyTextView.setText(data.get(position).getSal()) ;
           //familyTextView.setTypeface(bYekan);

           TextView nameTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
           nameTextView.setText(data.get(position).getNerkh()) ;
           //nameTextView.setTypeface(bYekan);

           Button detailsButton = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.detailsButton);
           detailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   //Toast.makeText(context, 
                       //  data.get(position).getSal() + " " + data.get(position).getNerkh(),
                       //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   Toast.makeText(context, 
                           data.size()+""  + " and ID is " +  position + "" ,
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
           });

           //item.startAnimation(animation);

           return item;
       }       


        } }
   ```

4.Shakhes.java

```
package ir.dadpardaz.mahrie_dadpardaz;

public class Shakhes {

    public int id ;
    public static String sal ;
    public static String nerkh ;



    public Shakhes(int id, String sal, String nerkh) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.sal = sal;
        this.nerkh = nerkh;
    }

    public Shakhes(String sal, String nerkh) {
        super();
        this.sal = sal;
        this.nerkh = nerkh;
    }

    public Shakhes() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSal() {
        return sal;
    }

    public void setSal(String sal) {
        this.sal = sal;
    }

    public String getNerkh() {
        return nerkh;
    }

    public void setNerkh(String nerkh) {
        this.nerkh = nerkh;
    }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your DataBaseHandler.java , Make the following change

```
 public List<Shakhes> getAllShakhes() {
    List<Shakhes> shakhess = null;

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TBL_MAHRIE",null);
    //Cursor c = database.query("TBL_MAHRIE", new String[] { "ID", "COL_SAL",   "COL_NERKH" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    shakhess = new ArrayList<Shakhes>();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {          
        do {
Shakhes p = new Shakhes();
            p.setId((int) c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("ID")));
            p.setSal(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_SAL")));
            p.setNerkh(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_NERKH")));

            shakhess.add(p);
        } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        return shakhess;

} 
    return shakhess;
   }
```

}

code the line `Shakhes p = new Shakhes();` inside do-while loop. Otherwise it will overwrite the old one, and the same will be added in arraylist.

Comment: thanks to Nizam , but unfortunately NOT WORKED. although I replaced your code , my activity repeat the last record instead of all records(6 times).I cleared the cache and uninstalled the application but nothing special happened.

Comment: Did you check your DB? Values inserted inside the table are correct? push the DB from DDMS file manager and check it.

Comment: yes , I've checked my data with an SQLite data browser plugin.Data are inserted correctly.

Comment: Ooooooooooooh , SOLVED , It was just because of that my variables was defined as static in Shakhes.java. thx to Nizam.